# Error connecting to principal SQL Server at same location from other location, error timeout. the secondary server connects fine

Tags: sql-server

I have an strange issue trying to connect from one server to the principal server. This is the setup.
All locations have SQL Server 2017. Updated to 2022-09-22
I have 3 locations: A, B and C.
In the location A, I have 2 servers. Principal (x.y.z0.21), secondary (x.y.z0.10)
In location B and C, Each one have 1 server, secondary (x.y.z1.10 and x.y.z2.10 respectly)
The location C is new.
The location B and C are connected with location A using VPN.
Location B and C are not reachable between them.

In location A, From "A secondary server", I can connect to "A principal server"
In location B, From "B secondary server", I can connect to both servers "A principal server" and "A secondary server"
In location C, From "C secondary server", I can connect server "A secondary server". The issue is that I can not connect to "a principal server"

I got this error:

> SQL DB pre-login handshake provider SSL error 0 the wait operation time out. Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258

I found very weird that "B server" can connect with both servers in location A, but "C server" can't do it, because if the issue were the network connection, the "C server" will be not able to connect with "A secondary server"

I have checked the setting in the SSMS in both location B and C, are the same.

Comment: Seems like a misconfigured firewall allowing the initial connection but then dropping it during the SSL/TLS handshake process. Helpful antivirus software?

Comment: I disabled the firewall on all servers. I only have windows defender.

I forgot to mention: The secondary server is a VM. the B and C seconday servers are a copy of Z seconday server (working also fine with both A Servers)

Comment: Still seems like firewall/network issues. On the C server... if you can't successfully  `telnet` from a Command Prompt (or [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection) from a PowerShell prompt) to A Primary and A Secondary servers on their designated TCP ports then SQL Server won't be able to connect to them either.

Comment: The C server is in a mobile location (on a vehicle), I moved to the A localtion. I connected the WAN port of C-router to a LAN port of A-router. I tried to connect with not success, then I remember the VPN and I disabled the VPN connection in the C-router (that try to connect to A-router using the external IP). After this I was able to connect. Later I connected the WAN port of C-router to a mobile internet g4, enable and connected successfully to the VPN with A-router but again I was enenable to connect to principal A-server. Then I'm thinking that the issue is the router. The B-VPN work fine